# Sums of even Divisor problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, divisor-sum

How to find sum of all even divisor of a number using formula.Or more efficiently​. Please any suggestions.

Comment: Do you know how to find the sum of all divisors?

Comment: Not. tell me please.

Comment: If you don't know how to find the sum of all divisors, why are you trying to find the sum of the even divisors? Do all divisors first, focus on prime factorisations, and then see if you can see what must be changed for even divisors. See if you can do it systematically in some way for easy examples where you can check by hand, like $6, 12, 15$ and $18$. Then see if the pattern you find holds for bigger numbers like $60, 72$ and $96$. Finally, write something you think is a general answer, and see if you can prove it. The only way to learn how to solve problems like these is to _do them_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code, the idea is to use the multiplicative formula but pre-sieving the primes first. Perhaps the only interesting idea is that the even divisors of $x$ are exactly the divisors of $x$ that are not divisors of the odd part of $x$.

This code should work within the time limits of most contest problems:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long lli;

const int MAX=1000010; // this will let us factorize number up to slightly less than MAX*MAX
int C[MAX];// the cribe
vector <int> P; //here we store the primes

lli sumd(lli x){
    lli res=1;
    for(int i=0;P[i]*P[i]<= x; i++){// by the prime number theorem this takes at most 2sqrt(n)/log(n) (approximately)
        lli m=1,f=1;// m is what we need to multiply the answer by at the end, f lets us build m
        while(x%P[i]==0){
            f*=P[i];
            m+=f;
            x/=P[i];
        }
        res=res*m;
    }
    if(x>1) res=res*(x+1);
    return(res);
}

int odd(int x){
    while(x%2){
        x/=2;
    }
    return(x);
}

int main(){
    for(int i=2;i<MAX;i++){// this sets up the cribe.
        if(!C[i]){
            P.push_back(i);
            for(int j=2*i;j<MAX;j+=i){
                C[j]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    int cases;
    cin >> cases;
    while(cases --){
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        cout << sumd(x)- sumd(odd (x) ) << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- The sum of divisors function $\sigma$ is a multiplicative function.  In other words, if $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime, then $\sigma(nm)=\sigma(n)\sigma(m)$.  Moreover, if $p$ is prime, then $\sigma(p)=p+1$.  Moreover $\sigma(p^k)=1+p+p^2+\cdots+p^k$, which is a geometric sum equal to $\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}$.
- The sum of the even divisors of $n$ is $\sigma(n)$ minus the sum of the odd divisors.
- If $2^k$ is the largest power of $2$ dividing $n$, then $\sigma\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)$ is the sum of the odd divisors of $n$.
- Putting this together, 
  \begin{align*}
  \sigma(n)-\sigma\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)&=\sigma(2^k)\sigma\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)-\sigma\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)\\
  &=\left(\sigma(2^k)-1\right)\sigma\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)\\
  &=(2^{k+1}-2)\sigma\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right).
  \end{align*}

For example, let $n=180=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5$.  Then, the divisors of $180$ are:
$$
\{1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,30,36,45,60,90,180\}.
$$
The sum of the divisors is
$$
1+2+3+4+5+6+9+10+12+15+18+20+30+36+45+60+90+180=546.
$$
The sum of the odd divisors is
$$
1+3+5+9+15+45=78.
$$
The sum of the even divisors is
$$
2+4+6+10+12+18+20+30+36+60+90+180=468.
$$
Observe that $468+78=546$ (as expected).

Alternately, we can use our formula to check all of this: The largest power of $2$ dividing $180$ is $2^2$, and $\frac{180}{4}=45$.  Therefore, the sum we're looking for can be computed as:
\begin{align*}
(2^3-2)\sigma(45)&=(2^3-2)\sigma(3^2)\sigma(5)\\
&=6\cdot\frac{3^3-1}{3-1}\cdot(5+1)\\
&=6\cdot 13\cdot 6=468.
\end{align*}
Observe additionally that $\sigma(45)=13\cdot 6=78$, i.e., the sum of the odd divisors.